# Can't download file with Run or CMD

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, download

So when I run this script

```
powershell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.somewebsite.com', 'Somefolder\Somefile.zip')
```

I get error

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:5
+ & { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.dropbox.com/ ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Comment: from your command, it looks like you broke the url to the file you want to download between both arguments. is your first argument the full url to the file, and is the second argument a valid path to a location on your local system? we can't tell based on what you posted. Second, if the site requires a login, try logging into the site and leaving that window open while executing the script.

Comment: it works perfectly with powershell, so that's out.

Comment: I just tried this with "https://www.google.com" and "index.html" from a cmd.exe window (no admin), and I got a 53k HTML file.

Comment: [It appears your syntax is faulty.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-6.0)  The address should be the full path to the file, while the filename should be, just the file you are attempting to download.  [However, I am confused, if "it works perfectly with PowerShell" and you are running it within PowerShell I am not sure what your question actually is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063242/powershell-2-files-execution-script).  Just adding quotes around the PowerShell command, or instead, provide the full path to ps and the .ps1

Comment: When I try to get it to run from CMD or Run Dialog it gives this error.

Comment: Or I could use an alternative to download file strictly with CMD.

Comment: @Jonas Try this format and see what happens: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf', 'C:\Test\Somefile.zip')"` change the URL and folder path accordignly. By the way, in my case, your example syntax worked 100% just fine from cmd, I assume it's an execution policy type think or maybe your cmd may need to the command parameter and the double quotes enclosing the command it will run. If that doesn't help, try it with `Invoke-Expression`

Comment: Try putting this in Run Dialog and you will get the same error.

Comment: @Jonas Nope, it worked from Run for me too no problem. Try running this and see what happens in case your system language local doesn't like the parenthesis or something funny like that: `PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" -OutFile "C:\Test\Somefile.zip"`. Try setting your `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` and then run the command. Maybe the execution policy when running from cmd or run from your system needs elevated in case your PowerShell run that works is PS session or profile specific. Just some quick ideas just in case.

Comment: @Jonas or `maybe Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` but try and test and see what happens. Set back to undefined or restricted when you're done testing. Everything seems to work for me that I run on Windows 10 21H2. I guess I should have asked what Operating System and build or version are you running this from.

Comment: I had this same problem with a batch build script I wrote.  I think it is the exact same scenario and have no idea why.  The problem was intermittent.  I ended up downloading a port of wget.exe and using that instead.  Haven't had a problem with it since.  You could also use curl but it is more complicated with nothing in return (for your case).

Comment: In response to the answer from @postanote , I was simply downloading a zip file from our own internal server using HTTP.  It had nothing to do with TLS.  Please let me know if postanote's answer worked (by marking correct!) if it does.  Something new to know.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using TLS these days to connect to the website because of the industry's change to the web.

```
# Required for use with web SSL sites
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

> See details:
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/?view=windowsserver2022-ps
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-gallery-tls-support
> https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Test-TlsProtocols/1.0.0

If you want them all in your code, just because, then this:

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
```